# Upload PDF's attachments to Arcgis Online

Tags: pdf, gis, attachment, arcgis

I'm adding PDF files as attachments to a point layer in Arcgis Online. If the file weights more than 2mb the upload fails (in fact there's no error or nothing like that, nothing happens but the file is not uploaded). The proceeding I'm using is: I add a point in editing mode, and I use the "choose file" button.
I've looked into the documentation and it says that the limit is 10mb.

Any ideas?